# Extract the contents from CSV into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a CSV file with contents:

```
John,1,2,4,67,100,41,234
Maria,45,23,67,68,300,250
```

I need to read this content and separate these data into two sections:

```
1.a Legend1 = John
1.b Legend2 = Maria
2.a Data_array1 = [1,2,4,67,100,41,234]
2.b Data_array2 = [45,23,67,a,67,300,250]
```

Here is my code; it reads the contents and separates the contents from `','`.

```
testsample = CSV.read('samples/linechart.csv')
CSV.foreach('samples/linechart.csv') do |row|
  puts row
end
```

Its output results in a class of array elements. I am stuck in pursuing it further.

Comment: Right now you are simply outputting each item from the enumerator that is returned from the `foreach` method.  If you use the `read` method from `CSV` library you will have an array that is returned that holds in each element an array that holds each item of the row.  This will help you pursue it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using CSV.read for this it's too simple for that - instead, use File.open and read each line and treat it as a big string.

eg:

```
# this turns the file into an array of lines
# eg you now have: ["John,1,2,4,67,100,41,234", "Maria,45,23,67,a,67,300,250"]
lines = File.readlines('samples/linechart.csv')

# if you want to do this for each line, just iterate over this array:
lines.each do |line|

  # now split each line by the commas to turn it into an array of strings
  # eg you have: ["john","1","2","4","67","100","41","234"]
   values = line.split(',')

  # now, grab the first one as you name and the rest of them as an array of strings
  legend = values[0]        # "john"
  data_array = values[1..-1]  # ["1","2","4","67","100","41","234"]

  # now do what you need to do with the name/numbers eg
  puts "#{legend}: [#{data_array.join(',')}]"

  # if you want the second array to be actual numbers instead of strings, you can convert them to numbers using to_i (or to_f if you want floats instead of integers)
  # the following says "take each value and call to_i on it and return the set of new values"
  data_array = data_array.map(&:to_i)

end # end of iterating over the array
```

Comment: Thanks Taryn for replying. How to convert                                                     ["1", "2", "4", "67", "100", "41", "234"]                                                            to display as                                                                                                        [1,2,4,67,100,41,234]

Comment: I add that. Are they always going to be numbers or possibly other strings?

Comment: The output is like this                                                                                       
John: [1,2,4,67,100,41,234
]

Matt: [45,23,67,67,300,250]                                                                                                                              I need a bit more help     I need to store the outputs  to variables and i will have to use them into a google chart                                                          1.a Legend1 = John
1.b Legend2 = Maria
2.a Data_array1 = [1,2,4,67,100,41,234]
2.b Data_array2 = [45,23,67,a,67,300,250]

Comment: I found the resolution for this . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First get the data out of csv like:

```
require 'csv'   
csv_text = File.read('/tmp/a.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text)
# => [["John", "1", "2", "4", "67", "100", "41", "234"], ["Maria", "45", "23", "67", "a", "67", "300", "250"]]
```

Now you can format output as per your requirements. Eg:

```
csv.each.with_index(1){ |a, i|
  puts "Legend#{i.to_s} = #{a[0]}"
}
# Legend1 = John
# Legend2 = Maria
```

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this,

```
csv = CSV.new(body)
csv.to_a
```

You can have a look at http://technicalpickles.com/posts/parsing-csv-with-ruby/

Reference [this](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/246-how-to-parse-csv-data-with-ruby), too, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Over-engineered version ;)

```
class Lines
  class Line
    attr_reader :legend, :array

    def initialize(line)
      @line = line
      parse
    end

    private

    def parse
      @legend, *array = @line.strip.split(",")
      @array = array.map(&:to_i)
    end
  end

  def self.parse(file_name)
    File.readlines(file_name).map do |line|
      Line.new(line)
    end
  end
end

Lines.parse("file_name.csv").each do |o|
  p o.legend
  p o.array
  puts
end

# Result:
#
# "John"
# [1, 2, 4, 67, 100, 41, 234]
#
# "Maria"
# [45, 23, 67, 68, 300, 250]
```

**Notes**:

1. Basically, `Lines.parse("file_name.csv")` will give you an array of objects that will respond to the methods: `legend` and `array`; which holds the *name* and *array of numbers* respectively.
2. Jokes aside, I think OO will help maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How to convert ["1", "2", "4", "67", "100", "41", "234"] to [1,2,4,67,100,41,234]

Comment: try this: `array.map(&:to_i)`. Assuming array holds that array.